# How to sort realm based on a field inside a deep nested object?

Tags: java, android, realm

I need to sort and get results based on a field which resides inside a deep nested object.

I need to sort the final result of a search query run on RealmObject A sorted based on the `String Id` field present in `RealmObject D`.

Consider the following as the RealmObject structure:

```
RealmObject A
- RealmObject B
- ..
- ..

RealmObject B
- RealmList<RealmObject C>
- ..
- ..

RealmObject C
- RealmList<RealmObject D>
- ..
- ..

RealmObject D
- String Id
- ..
- ..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe sorting on relation properties is not supported yet (querying is)

Comment: @TimCastelijns yea...look at the "+" here at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277 & corresponding issues at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1199 makes me feel the same but apparently we do have the `.findAll(fieldname.fieldname.fieldname)` feature then maybe it's not blocked by a core implementation for `sort` :| Maybe I'll just extend from an Abstract class and get a primary key or something across all the realmObjects and then proceed.

Comment: I suggest you query on the relation properties and then do the sorting manually

Comment: BTW, realm-cocoa issues are not relevant for realm-java, they are different projects

Comment: @TimCastelijns :D yep, my bad. Anyways, isn't the codebase for realm-core supposed to be the same?

Comment: Not sure about that, but cocoa and java don't share the same features

Comment: Can a `D` belong to multiple `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not supported yet. There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/672

As said above. It has up until now been a technical limitation in the underlying core, however, support for this was recently adding there so right now we just need to find the cycles to add support in the public API.

Until that happens the only workaround would be to add the field in `Item D` to `Item A`

Comment: thanks for the info! Yep I see it coming now :D Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

[Issue #672](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/672) has been resolved with [PR #3834](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3834)

**First:**
 
The example above to sort based on a field in a List is probably misleading, as it is not a valid thing to do.
To quote Christian Melchior:

> You are not able to sort a parent object based on a child list as it really doesn't make any sense, because which element in the list would you sort on? [src](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5255#issuecomment-328940879)

So to answer the initial question (assuming there is no list involved), it would look something like this:

```
RealmObjectA
- RealmObjectB objectB;

RealmObjectB
- RealmObjectC objectC;

RealmObjectC
- RealmObjectD objectD;

RealmObjectD
- String id;

realm.where( A.class ).findAllSorted("objectB.objectC.objectD.id");
```